# SQL - Get all rows of table one and count of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, count

How do I create an SQL query which gets all the rows of the table and count of rows inserted under e-mail?

I tried something like this, but this groups the rows and so I don't get all the rows.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(email) AS 'count' FROM adverts GROUP BY email
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select a1.*, a2.count
from adverts a1
join
(
  SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS 'count' 
  FROM adverts 
  GROUP BY email
) a2 on a1.email = a2.email
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
select *,
    (select count(Email) 
    from adverts  where adverts.Email =a.Email) as EmailCount
    from adverts as a
```

or this

```
SELECT *, COUNT(email) OVER (PARTITION BY  email) as EmailCount FROM adverts
```